# I want to cpy date between parent and child object

Tags: relationships, data

I have an object called `Opener__c`. And I have a second object called `Underwriting__c`. In `Underwriting__c` object I have a lookup field `Account__c` which is a relationship to the `Opener__c` object. When I'm creating new `Underwriting__c` record, I want to copy data from the `Opener__c` object.

So the question is: When I open the page for creating new `Underwriting__c` record I want to see fields populated with data from the `Opener__c` record.

I tried using triggers (before insert, before update) and when I click New button to create new `Underwriting__c` record I see page with fields to input data. And when I click save and my page refreshes I see that all fields are populated with data. But I want to populate data in fields on the page before I click save button.

Comment: You're going to need to associate the fields and then run an Action or a JS script after linking up the Account and the Underwriting record to the Opener record you want to pre-populate if you don't want to do this in a Trigger.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to populate the fields on the create/edit page of the underwriting object I believe this would require a custom VF page. The `<apex:page>` action method could fire a controller method to collect data you want to copy over from the related Account object and place it as values in the corresponding input fields for the new object.